# Abnormal behavior of speaker button on system provided call screen

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, portsip

We write VoIP application using CallKit and PortSIP and here is a problem is reproduced only on iOS 11.2.x.
When user taps speaker button on CallKit provided screen system enables speaker but icon remains in disabled state. If user taps again system also turns speaker on and forgets about button. To disable speaker user should tap button twice. Has anybody met this bug? And what was your solution? (:

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have solution  for this or fixed this issue any alternate?

Thanks,

Comment: @Madhu, nope. I've reported this bug to apple but they only ask me to send them sysdiagnose… again and again ):

Comment: Hi.. have same issue... did u fixed this?

Comment: I raised a bug for WebRTC with this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=9307#c1. Apps that don't use WebRTC (Like WhatsApp) are not having this issue.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. CallKit with WebRTC. Anyone found any alternate solution?

Comment: You may check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55413256/6064953
For me it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue has been experienced in the previous versions as well. So this is not the new issue happening on the call kit.

**This issue has to be resolved from iOS**. We don't have any control over this.

Answer (score 13):

```
    RTCDispatcher.dispatchAsync(on: RTCDispatcherQueueType.typeAudioSession) {
        let audioSession = RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        audioSession.lockForConfiguration()
        let configuration = RTCAudioSessionConfiguration.webRTC()
        configuration.categoryOptions = [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP,AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers,
                                         AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth]
        try? audioSession.setConfiguration(configuration)
        audioSession.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
```

It helps me for CallKit. Speaker button works as expected.

Comment: `func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    }`

Comment: I did it, and though it is not working. How Did you manage to do this?

Comment: Worked for me and I have no idea why. Thanks.

Comment: It works! And this should be the accepted answer despite not being an official workaround.

Comment: I'm using twilio-webrtc along with call-keep to handle video calling and callkit. It works fine so far but creates an issue while phone is locked and unable to handle event at that time. Any idea how to handle that scenario?

Comment: I tried this solution, though it's not working. Any suggestions to fix this issue ??

Comment: ```try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
            AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord,
            mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat,
            options: [.duckOthers, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .allowBluetooth]
        )```

I use it in all my projects. Maybe someone changes AVAudioSession after that

Comment: I've fixed my issue using this solution. Thanks @АлексейСмольский

Comment: Worked for me on CallKit and WebRTC combination. Thank you @АлексейСмольский

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: @АлексейСмольский "someone changes AVAudioSession after that" !!!!!! (Liveswitch)