# Callkit loudspeaker bug / how WhatsApp fixed it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, whatsapp, callkit

I have an app with `Callkit` functionality. When I press the loudspeaker button, it will flash and animate to the OFF state (sometimes the speaker is set to LOUD but the icon is still OFF). When I tap on it multiple times... it can be clearly seen that this functionality is not behaving correctly.

However, WhatsApp has at the beginning the loudspeaker turned OFF and after 3+ seconds it activates it and its working. Has anyone encountered anything similar and can give me a solution?

[Youtube video link to demonstrate my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs-T8GcXY2Y)

Answer (score 6):

There is a workaround proposed by an apple engineer which should fix callkit not activating the audio session correctly:

> a workaround would be to configure your app's audio session (call `configureAudioSession()`) earlier in your app's lifecycle, before the `-provider:performAnswerCallAction:` method is invoked. For instance, you could call `configureAudioSession()` immediately before calling `-[CXProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:update:completion:]` in order to ensure that the audio session is fully configured prior to informing CallKit about the incoming call.

From: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64544#189703

If this doesn't help, you probably should post an example project which reproduces your behaviour for us to be able to analyse it further.

Answer (score 3):

Above answer is correct, "VoiceChat" mode ruin everything.

**Swift 4** example for WebRTC. 
After connection was established call next

```
let rtcAudioSession = RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance()
rtcAudioSession.lockForConfiguration()
do {
    try rtcAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord.rawValue, with: 
    AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
    try rtcAudioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.default.rawValue)
    try rtcAudioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
    try rtcAudioSession.setActive(true)
} catch let error {
    debugPrint("Couldn't force audio to speaker: \(error)")
}
rtcAudioSession.unlockForConfiguration()
```

You can use AVAudioSession.sharedInstance() as well instead RTC

Answer (score 0):

Referd from [Abnormal behavior of speaker button on system provided call screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023629/abnormal-behavior-of-speaker-button-on-system-provided-call-screen?rq=1)

The same issue has been experienced in the previous versions as well. So this is not the new issue happening on the call kit.
This issue has to be resolved from iOS. We don't have any control over this.

Please go through the apple developer forum

[CallKit/detect speaker set](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/96243)

and

[[CALLKIT] audio session not activating?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/202644#202644)

Comment: Nope. I have not frozen display like u saying. Its working but I need to double tap Speaker button to activate it and its deactivating itself.

Comment: I think this is not an issue of CallKit Functionality. You can restart you iPhone and then try. Sometimes iPhone does not respond properly so you can restart and then try it.

Comment: Swati: i have iph 5, 6, 6s, iphX. On all of these devices you have to push twice to see active loud speaker and its behaviour its not correct. All other buttons working OK but speaker is not doing well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can setMode to AVAudioSessionModeDefault.

When I use CallKit + WebRTC

1. I configure AVAudioSessionModeDefault mode.
2. Alloc CXProvider and reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID
3. Use WebRTC , after ICEConnected, WebRTC change mode to AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat, then speaker issue happen.
4. Later I setMode back to AVAudioSessionModeDefault, the speaker works well.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by doing following steps.

- In CXAnswerCallAction, use below code to set audiosession config.

  ```
  RTCDispatcher.dispatchAsync(on: RTCDispatcherQueueType.typeAudioSession) {
  let audioSession = RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance()
  audioSession.lockForConfiguration()
  let configuration = RTCAudioSessionConfiguration.webRTC()
  configuration.categoryOptions = [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP,AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers,
                                   AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth]
  try? audioSession.setConfiguration(configuration)
  audioSession.unlockForConfiguration()}
  ```
- After call connected, I'm resetting AudioSession category to default.

  ```
  func configureAudioSession() {
  let session = RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance()
  session.lockForConfiguration()
  do {            
      try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord.rawValue, with: .allowBluetooth)
      try session.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.default.rawValue)
      try session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
      try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
  } 
  catch let error {
      debugPrint("Error changeing AVAudioSession category: \(error)")
  }
  session.unlockForConfiguration()}
  ```

Thanks to [SO @Алексей Смольский](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806266/4014369) for the help.

Comment: hi, where to put code configureAudioSession? You mean rtc is connected or call is connected?